# Prove an equality involving ratios with sample-means and variances.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance, means, ratio

We sampled $n$ observations  $X_1,...,X_n$ from a location-scale family's distribution and $Y_1,...,Y_m$ from the same distribution but different parameters.

How does one show that

> $\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}+\sum_{1}^{m}\left(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}\right)^{2}}{\sum_{1}^{n}\left\{X_{i}-[(n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}) /(n+m)]\right\}^{2}+\sum_{1}^{n}\left\{Y_{i}-[(n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}) /(n+m)]\right\}^{2}} =\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}+\sum_{1}^{m}\left(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}\right)^{2}}{\sum_{1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}+\sum^{m}\left(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}\right)^{2}+[n m /(n+m)](\bar{X}-\bar{Y})^{2}}?$

---

Assume these are true

> $$
> \sum_{1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2}=\sum_{1}^{n}\left[\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)+\left(\bar{X}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)\right]^{2}
> $$
> $$
> =\sum_{1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2}+n\left(\bar{X}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2}
> $$
> and
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \sum_{1}^{m}\left(Y_{i}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2} &=\sum_{1}^{m}\left[\left(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}\right)+\left(\bar{Y}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)\right]^{2} \\
> &=\sum_{1}^{m}\left(Y_{i}-\bar{Y}\right)^{2}+m\left(\bar{Y}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> But
> $$
> n\left(\bar{X}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2}=\frac{m^{2} n}{(n+m)^{2}}(\bar{X}-\bar{Y})^{2}
> $$
> and
> $$
> m\left(\bar{Y}-\frac{n \bar{X}+m \bar{Y}}{n+m}\right)^{2}=\frac{n^{2} m}{(n+m)^{2}}(\bar{X}-\bar{Y})^{2}
> $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{m^2 n}{(n+m)^2} + \frac{n^2 m}{(n+m)^2} = \frac{nm}{(n+m)^2} (m+n) = \frac{nm}{n+m}.$$